# convert list of list to dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
list = [[1,1,56],
        [20,2,78],
        [30,3,34],
        [40,4,98]]
```

this is my list of list  and i want to make a dataframe like this-;

```
a  b  c
1  1  56
20 2  78
30 3  34
40 4  98
```

i did a code

`df = pd.DataFrame(list)
df = df.transpose()
df.columns = ["a", "b", "c"]`

it gives me a error like  `Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 3 elements`

please help me
thanks in advance

Comment: remove the transpose line and it will work as expected

Comment: Why not `df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=["a", "b", "c"])` ?

Comment: **Remove the transpose.** `df = pd.DataFrame(list)` gives you a df of dimensions (4 rows, 3 cols). Transpose changes it to (3 rows, 4 cols) and then you will have to 4 col names instead of three.

Comment: what @jezarel suggested is the proper way to do it

Comment: all of you guys , thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First dont use `list` because reserved code word in python and then only pass columns parameter, `transpose` is not necessary:

```
L = [[1,1,56],
      [20,2,78],
      [30,3,34],
      [40,4,98]]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=["a", "b", "c"])
print (df)
    a  b   c
0   1  1  56
1  20  2  78
2  30  3  34
3  40  4  98
```

Comment: and if i want to convert that (dataframe into list  of list) , how can we do that?

Comment: Use `L = df.values.tolist()`

Comment: amazing bro, take a HUG from my-side<3